# Java applet debugging: port does not open for debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I am using Java 8. I am trying to debug an applet for which I had set up below runtime parameters in java configuration:

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=7901,suspend=n
```

But the given port 7901 does not show up when I do the `netstat /a`

So while trying to start remote application with the given port for localhost and connection type as `Standard(Socket Attach)` in eclipse, it always fails to connect to the vm.

After setting/changing the port in the runtime parameters, is there any further step to bring up the port? If not then what could be the reason of port not coming up in netstat?

Answer (score 0):

I had Java x64 and x86 both installed in my system. The java config in control panel opens the config for x64 and apperently my applet was using x86 java. So I executed `javacpl.exe` for x86 java manually and set the runtime parameters in config. After that the port shows up in netstat.